# How to remote_write only a subset of all scraped metrics in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

Trying to understand if there's a way to send only certain metrics to a remote storage using remote_write kind of like federation endpoint scraping.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer, not sure how I missed it in the first place:

> write_relabel_configs is relabeling applied to samples before sending them to the remote endpoint. Write relabeling is applied after external labels. This could be used to limit which samples are sent.

From https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write

Answer (score 1):

Following up to @Maklaus answer to their question above, the `keep` action of [write_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write) can be used to only write certain metrics. For example, to only write metrics with names `metric1` and `metric2`, you can do:

```yaml
write_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: ["__name__"]
      regex: "^metric1$|^metric2$"
      action: keep
```